# Using multi-touch input in GUI interactivity?

Tags: .net, user-interface, multi-touch

I would like to implement multi-touch in my applications for Windows Mobile. The applications will mostly use it for zoom related actions e.g. two points (touched) **moving towards each other** while relatively moving towards a certain point will zoom IN to that point, where two touched points moving **away from each other** will do the exact opposite: zoom OUT.

I understand that people will use certain *gestures* with their fingers, toes or stumps to accomplish this UI behaviour/interactivity. Does this mean I can get sued by Apple?

> - [ref](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2360838,00.asp)
> - [ref2](http://thenextweb.com/us/2010/03/02/apple-htc-google-multitouch/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a patent-legal question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's a question you better ask your lawyer.

IANAL, but IMHO the easiest way would be to start/join a worldwide lobbying group against software patents. At least against trivial software patents. Your goal: Reform the patent system in a way that such stuff is regarded as "too trivial to be patent worthy".

(I never said it would be easy. I just think this is the easiest way without paying or risking to be sued.)